# Pegar evento de click no valor do autocomplete do jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo uma função em *JQuery* que usa o componente *Autocomplete* onde busco o nome da empresa e mude em outro campo o nome da empresa.

Exemplo:

Campo1 (autocomplete) passa informação para Campo2 quando é clicado na opção que aparece do Autocomplete.

O meu problema é: Saber qual o valor que foi clicado e o evento de click para passar para o outro campo a informação.

Segue trecho de código:

```
var empresas = ['teste','teste2'];
$( "#e" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: empresas
});
```

Comment: `select: function (e, i) {
               console.log(i.item.val);  }`, já tentou?

Comment: Não tinha tentando pois não sabia qual era a funçao para pegar o evento, e não tinha achado uma solução, funcionou essa trocando val por value

Comment: Bom que pude ajudar, se clicar em executar lá em baixo vai ver funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o evento `select`. Fiz um teste com base no exemplo do próprio site do [Jquery-UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

*Ficaria assim:*

```js
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: function (e, i) {
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Você selecionou o item: " + i.item.value
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
  <div id='msg'>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta sobrescrever a função callback original:

```
function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
{                        
    $('#Campo2').val(ui.item.value);
}
```

ou desta forma, adicionando o callback `select`:
[API jQuery](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)

```
var empresas = ['teste','teste2'];
$( "#e" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    source: empresas,
    select: function( event, ui ) { $('#Campo2').val(ui.item.value); }
});
```

Comment: Deu certo essa, a diferença que troque o search por select e o label por value