# Como pegar o item pesquisado com autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um autocomplete que funciona perfeitamente. Como que eu faço para pegar o item pesquisado e colocar dentro de uma div? Tipo pesquiso x-salada e quando clicar ele coloque x-salada dentro da div. A função AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui) não retorna nada.

```
// BUSCA COM AUTOCOMPLETE
var resultadoLanche = [];
// Captura o retorno do retornaCliente.php
$.ajax({
  url: urlBase + "produtos?filter[categoria_id]=" + idcategoria,
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(retorno)
  {

    retorno.data.forEach(function(item)
    {
      resultadoLanche.push(item.nome);

    });
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
    alert("Status do Servidor: " + textStatus);
    alert("Erro do Servidor: " + errorThrown);
  }
});

// ativar o autocomplete
$('#buscarProduto').autocomplete(
  {
    source: resultadoLanche,
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
      $('#buscarProduto').val(ui.item.value);
    },
    minLength: 3
  }
);

function AutoCompleteSelectHandler(event, ui)
{
  alert('teste');
var teste = $('#buscarProduto').val(ui.item.value);

}
```

Comment: Seria isto? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155746/pegar-evento-de-click-no-valor-do-autocomplete-do-jquery/155752#155752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é necessário o uso da função *AutoCompleteSelectHandler* neste caso.
Basta aqui no seu *select*

```
select: function(event, ui)
{
  $('#buscarProduto').val(ui.item.value);
},
```

você substituir o código `$('#buscarProduto').val(ui.item.value);` para `$('#buscarProduto').html(ui.item.value);`. Se o *value* existir, será inserido na div. Normalmente o *val()* insere e captura informações de *inputs*.
Faz esse teste e vê se consegue resolver!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta substituir:

```
$('#buscarProduto').val(ui.item.value);
```

Pelo ID da respectiva div e a função .text()

```
$('#divParaExibir').text(ui.item.value);
```